# What is wrong with this Macro?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macros

```
#define mySynthesize(op) @synthesize op = _op;
```

So rather than typing

```
@synthesize someVar=_someVar;
@synthesize otherVar=_otherVar;
```

I can just do

```
mySynthesize (someVar);
```

Well, it doesn't work though. What did I do wrong?

Comment: did you not just ask the same macro question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472063/i-want-to-create-a-simple-macro ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you prefix the `op` with an underscore, the preprocessor treats it as a different token, so it doesn't get replaced. You need to use `##` to concatenate the underscore to the front so that the replacement occurs first.

```
#define mySynthesize(op) @synthesize op = _ ## op
```

Comment: @bigkm: Stringification is something entirely different. I think you were looking for this http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html